# Building a new Cocos2d javascript project fails

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-iphone

I've just installed cocos2d-iphone and installed the XCode templates as described [here](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/wiki/cocos2d-and-JavaScript). I've created a new "Cocos2d OSX with JavaScript"-project. Now, when I try to run the new project, I get a build error in `jsb_core.mm`, complaining that `jsb_opengl_registration.h` is not found. I've tried to google `jsb_opengl_registration.h`, but nothing turns up.

Do anyone out there know how to deal with this? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out that, the jsb lib binding template templates/Xcode4_templates/lib_jsbindings.xctemplate/TemplateInfo.plist was falling behind a little. The problem has been resolved in https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/commit/32fe67c6f31684dd3a235f6dfb5e64f49ce2edfc, so doing a fetch and installing the templates again fixes the problem.